# DataReader does not return value?

Tags: c#, mysql

I wrote a program in C# where I wanted to get a value from a MySQL Database.

My code is:

```
MySqlCommand queryReqYear =
      new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT req_year FROM subjects_offered
                         WHERE subj_code= @subj", connectToDB.connection);


queryReqYear.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subj", viewStudents_subj.SelectedValue);
```

Then I use DataReader

```
MySqlDataReader reader;
reader = queryReqYear.ExecuteReader();
```

And then I try to get the value:

```
while (reader.Read())
    { MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString(0)); }
```

The field I'm trying to get has a value of *3*. I'm trying to display that value but when I execute the event, nothing happens.

EDIT

Okay, I solved the problem by changing `SelectedValue` to `SelectedItem`

Comment: If nothing happens then reader.Read() is probably returning false because the result set is empty. Where are you setting the value of `@subj`? What are you setting it to?

Comment: That's from user input.   queryReqYear.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subj", viewStudents_subj.SelectedValue); I can assure you that the field I'm querying is NOT empty. It has a value of 3.

Comment: Does `reader.Read()` return `true` or `false`? If it returns `false` your query is not returning any records. Also, I didn't say the field was empty, I said the result set is empty.

Comment: What happens when you run the statement (including the 'blah') in let's say HeidiSQL?

Comment: can you post the whole code of the procedure? because we can't automatically determine if the error is from that line. It may be on the connection, or your sqlcommand does not have enough value.

Comment: Yes, if I explicitly put a string value on WHERE subj_code = ____, I get the result I want. But when I try to use Parameters, it comes up empty. The parameter value is coming from a combobox item, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved the problem by changing `SelectedValue` to `SelectedItem`

Answer (score 1):

try `Text` property:

```
queryReqYear.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subj", viewStudents_subj.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting single quotes around blah in your sql statement.

```
MySqlCommand queryReqYear =
  new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT req_year FROM subjects_offered
                     WHERE subj_code= 'blah'", connectToDB.connection);
```

Comment: EDIT: It works if I do it like that. But when use Parameters.AddWithValue, the result is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get any exceptions, just not result?

You may want to test out putting this into a variable, then making a code break, something like:

```
string testValue = reader.GetString(0);
Console.WriteLine(testValue);
```

Also, you should test your SQL code in a SQL client to see if you get the proper results there.  I suspect your SQL is the problem, not the c# code.

Comment: I'm getting the result if I directly put a value on WHERE subj_code. But when I use Parameters.AddWithValue, it returns empty.